# assistance with fxcop

Tags: msbuild, code-analysis, tfsbuild, fxcop

I am at present developing a mvc4 project that comunicates to a set of wcf services. I am setting such up in tfs build for a team of developers.

I am very much a newbie to fxcop and code analysis in general. I am currently researching it and have some questions following this:

- Is it recommended to use the rules that come with fxcop?
- Should it be included as a build task during builds?
- What is the value from it?
- Are there guidelines to what rules to abide by or is it best to go with the default?
- Is it correct to run the analysis as a post build event?

I am a newbie to fxcop and would like some feedback. I am as it is integrating stylecop in to my build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [haacked](http://haacked.com/) blog post: http://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx.

I think it answers most of your questions. Some of the pointers are:

**Is it recommended to use the rules that come with fxcop?**

For a new project I would enable all rules, and over time disable the ones you find distracting. For an existing project, I would enable minimal rules, and over time slowly add new rules and clean up the code as required.

The code analysis rules are:

- [Design Warnings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182125)
- [Globalization Warnings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182184)
- [Interoperability Warnings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182193)
- [Maintainability Warnings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182211)
- [Mobility Warnings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182218)
- [Naming Warnings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182232)
- [Performance Warnings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182260)
- [Portability Warnings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182282)
- [Reliability Warnings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182287)
- [Security Warnings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182296)
- [Usage Warnings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182324)

**Should it be included as a build task during builds?**

Yes. This is the method I used: http://kentb.blogspot.co.nz/2011_01_01_archive.html

It can be enabled via the UI if your IDE supports it. However I had issues when different projects used different rulesets (eg, a unit test project may be more relaxed). The procedure from kentb's blog works around that issue.

Alternatively you could call FxCop directly from a post build event.

**What is the value from it?**

Well structured code and reduced production issues.

**Are there guidelines to what rules to abide by or is it best to go with the default?**

Again - go with whatever works for you. For example, you may not care that the binaries are not strongly named. The haacked blog post has some good pointers.

**Is it correct to run the analysis as a post build event?**

If you follow kentb's blog post, or enable it via the IDE GUI (assuming your IDE supports it), then it will be run as part of the build process. If you call FxCop directly, then it will need to be done as a post build event.

Comment: Excellent feedback, learned a significant amount from it. I am developing an application that will support different/cultures and languages so this is very important for me.